# Code works at PhP but not at VB

Tags: php, vb.net, curl

I tried to execute some code accessing livecoin API.

Using fiddler my post commands if with vb.net is the following (I put my API key but not my secret, so it's safe).

```
POST https://api.livecoin.net/exchange/cancellimit HTTP/1.1
Api-Key: 5Gs9BQ4RTggMPwWMwkzvCnGdvhcn6FfN
Sign: 5BA7FC2C46DC781FCCF37F78C0DB6E791BF3F7CFCA65B99C2E36A826B416A557
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Pragma: no-cache
Host: api.livecoin.net
Content-Length: 40
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

currencyPair=BTC%2FUSD&orderId=496303677
```

That doesn't work. I got this response

```
{"success":true,"cancelled":false,"message":"Failed to cancelOrder[orderId={1}]|0[Unknown currency pair [currencyPair={1}]|null]"}
```

If I use curl

The post message is this

```
POST https://api.livecoin.net/exchange/cancellimit HTTP/1.1
Host: api.livecoin.net
Accept: */*
Api-Key: 5Gs9BQ4RTggMPwWMwkzvCnGdvhcn6FfN
Sign: 5BA7FC2C46DC781FCCF37F78C0DB6E791BF3F7CFCA65B99C2E36A826B416A557
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

currencyPair=BTC%2FUSD&orderId=496303677
```

This one works.

```
{"success":true,"cancelled":false,"message":"Order[orderId={1}] isn't in OrderBook: status={1}|496303677|CANCELLED"}
```

Which is correct. That's what it should be. Notice the post content is exactly the same. Even the signature is the same.

I wonder why the post command that is almost exactly the same like that can produce two different result.

The one I want to use in production is the vb.net one.

The actual code

```
Protected Overrides Function getJsonPrivate(method As String, otherParameters() As Tuple(Of String, String)) As String
    Dim Uri As String
    otherParameters = otherParameters.ToList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Item1).ToArray

    Dim param = jsonHelper.createPostStringFromTupples(otherParameters) 'orderId=495852754&currencyPair=BTC/USD
    Uri = "https://api.livecoin.net/" + method '
    Dim HMACSHA256 = New HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secret1))
    Dim sig = ExchangesClass.CalculateSignature2(param, HMACSHA256).ToUpper
    Dim headers = {Tuple.Create("Api-Key", _apiKey1), Tuple.Create(Of String, String)("Sign", sig)}

    Dim result = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1(Uri, param, headers)
    Return result
End Function
```

That one code works fine in most scenario.

```
Public Shared Function downloadString1(url As String, post As String, otherHeaders As Tuple(Of String, String)()) As String
    Dim wc = New CookieAwareWebClient()
    For Each oh In otherHeaders
        wc.Headers.Add(oh.Item1, oh.Item2)
    Next

    Dim response = String.Empty

    Try
        If post = "" Then
            response = wc.DownloadString(url)
        Else
            response = wc.UploadString(url, post)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim a = 1
    End Try

    Return response
End Function

   Public Shared Function downloadString1(url As String, post As String, otherHeaders As Tuple(Of String, String)()) As String
        Dim wc = New CookieAwareWebClient()
        For Each oh In otherHeaders
            wc.Headers.Add(oh.Item1, oh.Item2)
        Next

        Dim response = String.Empty

        Try
            If post = "" Then
                response = wc.DownloadString(url)
            Else
                response = wc.UploadString(url, post)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim a = 1
        End Try

        Return response
    End Function
```

It seems that the problem is the way livecoin api interpret currencyPair=BTC%2FUSD

But as I said, both have exact same post content.

Comment: You probably need to set the content-type (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Comment: probably shouldn't post your api key and signature on here...

Comment: It can only be used to cancel one already canceled order. Nothing else. Not without the API secret.

Comment: @FirstOne would you please turn that into an answer?

Comment: @J.Chang I probably shouldn't since I don't know how to do that in vb.net xD.. If you fixed it (I'm glad I was of any help), you can post how you did it.

Comment: Please turn that into answer and I will accept. Otherwise I would answer it my self. You saved me hours of debugging. That is indeed the problem.